# Add or remove class from all <li> and <a>

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="nirmohi">
    <div align="left" class="nimicontainer nimileft clearfix">
        <ul class="dropdown dropdown-h dropdownleft">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Administration</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Project</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Well Known Staff</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sltd1"><a class="sltd2" href="#">Mental Health And Education</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Patient Enquiry</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Employment</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Site Map</a>
            </li>
        </ul>`enter code here`</div>
</div>
```

When I click the anchor within one of the li's I want to set it to sltd1
and for a's sltd2.
I want to add that class in li's and a's when clicked. and remove previous clicked.
pls help me asap.
I want this coz i have two background images.

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried and we'd be glad to help.

Comment: We do not write code for you here at SO. But here are some links that might help [Add Class](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) [Remove Class](http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 4):

```
 $(".dropdown li,.dropdown li a").live("click", function(){ 

$('li  a').removeClass('myclass');
$('li a').addClass('myclass');
$('li').removeClass('myclass');
$('li').addClass('myclass');  

});
```

Comment: [`live` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live), as it binds to the whole document and can thus slow things down unnecessarily. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("li,a") .removeAttr('class');
```

to add class

```
$("li,a") .addClass('classname');
```

this will add classname on li and a

Answer (score 1):

You can directly `.removeclass()` like

```
$('li a').removeClass('myclass');
```

And if you want to add class then use `.adClass()` like

```
$('li a').addClass('myclass');
```

Answer (score 1):

We want to attach a click event listener to every `a` element. The closest parent is `.nirmohi`, so we should select that and listen for clicks on any `a` within it:

```
$('.nirmohi').on('click', 'a', clicked);
```

I've referenced a function there, `clicked`, that we'll have to define:

```
function clicked(e) {
    // ...
}
```

Within `clicked`, `this` will refer to the DOM element that was clicked. That's fine for some purposes, but we want to make it back into a jQuery object. To do that, pass it into the jQuery function.

Once you have it as a jQuery object, you can add a class using `addClass`. For example, if the jQuery object was in `el`, I could quite easily add a class; for example, `featured`:

```
el.addClass('featured');
```

`removeClass` works similarly.

You could access the parent element to add or remove classes to it, too; just use `parent`. For example, to get the parent of `el`:

```
var parentEl = el.parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use jquery `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()`.

```
$('li').addClass('ABC');//-- AddClass on <li>
$('a').addClass('ABC'); //-- AddClass on <a>
$('li').removeClass('ABC'); //-- RemoveClass on <li>
$('a').removeClass('ABC'); //-- RemoveClass on <li>
```

[AddClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[RemoveClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 0):

to remove all the classes

```
$("li,a") .removeAttr('class');
```

to remove a classs

```
$('li,a').removeClass('ClassName');
```

to add a class

```
$('li,a').addClass('ClassName');
```

to toggle class

```
$('li,a').toggleClass('ClassName');
```